# Некорректное отображение datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, margin

Ситуация следующая.
Есть datepicker, который имеет 2 варианта выпадения: над формой и под ней.

[image: Под формой]
[image: Над формой]

Стоит задача увеличить вертикальный отступ от формы до выпадающего блока. 
Вариант с margin не подходит, т.к. когда блок "выпадает" наверх, margin-top смещает его вниз, и он начинает перекрывать форму.
 Отступы необходимо сделать одинаковые в 2х случаях выпадения. 
Как через js/jquery определить куда выпадает блок и, в зависимости от этого, добавлять соответствующие классы типа ui-datepicker__top / ui-datepicker__bottom . 
Или может есть более изящное решение? 
К слову, все это крутится на Yii2.

Блок изначально спозиционирован абсолютно и спрятан.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При появлении идет подсчет координат через datepicker.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае, с несколькими полям ввода дат мне помогло следующее: 
Заново инициализировать поля с нужными опциями.

```
$(".default.datepicker-big").datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonText: "<svg class='svg-ico calendar-big'><use xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' xlink:href='/frontfiles/img/svg/sprite.svg#ico-calendar'></use></svg>",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    buttonImageOnly: false,
    dateFormat: 'mm.dd.yy',
});
```

Сравнивать .offset().top блока datepicker с .offset().top кнопки через которую он вызван.

```
var uiDatepickerDiv = $('#ui-datepicker-div');

$(".ui-datepicker-trigger").on('click', function(){
$(this).offset().top <= uiDatepickerDiv.offset().top ? uiDatepickerDiv.addClass('to-bottom').removeClass('to-top') : uiDatepickerDiv.addClass('to-up').removeClass('to-bottom');
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо выставить нужному блоку `position: absolute;`, а также поставить его в нужное положение, например `top: 100px;` и `left: 200px;`
А при нужном действии, например: спускать нужный блок на 100px вниз.

```
$('блок, который надо сдвинуть').css('top', 'значение отступа');
```

Если будет проблема с перекрыванием, то нужно поработать с атрибутом `z-index`

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Добавил немного ясности, отредактировав вопрос. Сейчас смотрю в сторону showOptions.
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-showOptions